# Why does 2 && 3 results in 3 (javascript)?

Tags: javascript, logic, logical-operators

When I type in browser's console:

```
console.log(2 && 3)
```

it results always with second number (in this case 3):

```
3
```

Can someone explain me why?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If the left hand side of `&&` evaluates as a false value, the whole expression evaluates as the left hand side.

Otherwise it evaluates as the right hand side.

`2` is a true value, so `2 && 3` is `3`.

For comparison, try `console.log(0 && 1)` and `console.log(false && "something")`.

Answer (score 9):

The [&& logical operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_AND_(.26.26)) will return the last value if all other values are truthy else it will return the first non truthy value.

So in your case since 2 is truthy then it will evaluate `3` and since that is truthy it will be returned.

Same way `2 && 0 && 4` will return `0` as it is a non truthy value.

[Logical Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators)

> Logical operators are typically used with Boolean (logical) values.
>   When they are, they return a Boolean value. However, the && and ||
>   operators actually return the value of one of the specified operands,
>   so if these operators are used with non-Boolean values, they may
>   return a non-Boolean value.

Answer (score 6):

`&&` has to evaluate all expressions. `2 && 3` will first evaluate the “truthiness” of `2` which is a true value but then it has to evaluate `3` as well. That last evaluated value is then returned. If at least one value is non-truthy then the first such value is returned instead.

`||` on the other hand returns the *first truthy* expression or the last non-truthy if there are no truthy expressions.

The reason why `&&` returns the last possible value is that it simply has to check *all* expressions in order to return a result. `||` doesn’t have to do that. If the first expression for `||` is true it ignores all further ones. Likewise if the first expression for `&&` is false it ignores all further ones (see short-circuiting in logical operators).